# EasyAdminBundle transliterator_transliterate ошибка при загрузке файлов

Tags: symfony4, easyadmin

Я использую EasyAdmin поля формы в такой кофигурации в easy_admin.yaml:

```
- { property: 'imageFile', type: 'file_upload', type_options: { upload_dir: 'public/data/gallery/images/', upload_filename: '[uuid]-[timestamp].[extension]'}}
```

Когда я загружаю файл - я получаю ошибку:

```
Attempted to call function "transliterator_transliterate" from namespace "EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Form\Type".
```

Если убрать эту часть - то все загружается нормально:

```
upload_filename: '[uuid]-[timestamp].[extension]'
```

В чем может быть ошибка в описании паттерна названия файла?

Answer (score 0):

Я поняла, что Symfony так сообщает о том, что функция "transliterator_transliterate" не существует. У меня был `php-intl` выключен на сервере - разкомментирование этой строчки  `;extension=php_intl.dll` в `php.ini` решает проблему.